# Stock value import XML feed with variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stock, wpallimport, product-variations

I would like to import a XML feed with stock values. I would like to import the stock of a SKU to multiple SKU's in woocommerce. (we have a printing company where you can buy branded merchandise, a bottle for instance has different variations based on color and printing colors.

The issue is that we have variations of the green bottle like green bottle with 1 print color, 2 print color etc. Yellow 1 print color etc.
The different color bottles have their own SKU as well as the the print colors. However the green bottle with 1 print color has the same stock value as the green bottle with 2 print colors as they are the same bottle.

With WP all import i can import the stock values only it displays it on one combination. Green bottle 1 print color, but i want to show it on different combinations. I have added a description on the variations and named it the SKU of the green bottle. So Green bottle 1 print color has the same SKU as 2 print colors, 3 print colors etc. However WP all import.

Is there a solution to this? I found a code and tried to change it to something like below but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

function get_product_by_variation_description( $meta_value ) {

    // Access WPDB object.
    global $wpdb;

    // Match by our files variation description and ignore slashes in the  database.
    $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_key FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_variation_description'='%s'LIMIT 100", $_variation_description ) );

    // If a match was found return its value.
    if ( $product_id ) return $product_id;

    return null;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately not, i exported the items in a csv file and created a google sheet document. In this document i imported the XML feed and in the main sheet i connected the items with the stock values of the XML feed. This way i made an online conversion of the XML feed, so in a way i created my one XML feed which refreshes daily.